# Como realizar un sum() de otra suma realizada previamente en tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

actualmente estoy trabajando un proyecto en laravel 8 y me encontré con un problema que quisiera saber si se puede realizar en una sola consulta.

Necesito realizar una consulta para traer una lista de clientes: en la cual debo mostrar los siguientes datos: **Id**, **Nombre** y **Total de compras** (Monto total de las compras que ha realizado el cliente).

Entonces para ello debo consultar 3 tablas.

| Cliente | Venta | Detalle_venta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
| nombre | id_cliente | venta_id |
| email | num_comprobante | producto_id |
| telefono | fecha_hora | cantidad_a_vender |
|  |  | predio_de_venta |

Comprendo que debo de hacer joins para unir las tablas. o utilizar las funciones with para las relaciones.

Donde me surge el problema es al tratar de recolectar el campo **Total de compras (Monto total de las compras que ha realizado el cliente)**.

Ya que para ello debo realizar un sum('cantidad_a_vender * precio_de_venta') -> con esto obtengo el total de una venta individual. pero luego debo aplicar otro sum() para sumar esos totales y así obtener un monto total de todas la compras realizadas por el cliente correspondiente.

y realmente quiero saber si es posible obtener ese resultado en una sola consulta. intente de muchas maneras pero no logré realizarlo.

Comment: No sería ideal almacenar en una variable el resultado de la suma para posteriormente volver a sumarlo en otra consulta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la forma de realizarlo!

Dejaré el resultado por acá por si a alguien más le puede servir en un caso similar.

Para poder resolverlo, como primera parte apliqué un **sum('cantidad_a_vender * precio_de_venta')** para poder sacar el total de cada venta individual, y luego apliqué **GroupBy** para agruparlos por los clientes, de esa manera logro sacar el monto total de compras por cada cliente.

```
$clientes = Venta::select('cliente.id', 'cliente.nombre')
->selectRaw('SUM(detalle_venta.cantidad * detalle_venta.precio_venta)')
->join('cliente', 'cliente.id', '=', 'venta.cliente_id')
->join('detalle_venta', 'venta.id', '=', 'detalle_venta.venta_id')
->groupBy('cliente.id', 'cliente.nombre')
->get();
```